# OSX Install problem - rqt_top: No definition of [python-psutil] for OS [osx]

Tags: rosdep, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm trying to walk through the latest OSX install instructions. I have gotten to this step:

rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

When I encountered this error:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rqt_top: No definition of [python-psutil] for OS [osx]

I'm on 10.8.3 and this is the first time I've tried to install ROS on this laptop. (If that matters)

Suggestions for debugging ideas would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80446/osx-install-problem---rqt_top:-no-definition-of-%5Bpython-psutil%5D-for-os-%5Bosx%5D/) by [iandanforth](https://answers.ros.org/users/6821/iandanforth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Update** 9/23/2013) patch is accepted and the reported issue should not longer be the case.

---

That's because `psutil` is missing in `OSX`' [rosdep key](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml).

---

Here is tentative workaround before the `rosdep` key gets updated. Since this involves modifying protected area, **do it at your own risk**.

I have [a patch](https://github.com/130s/rosdistro/commit/4f844dad3602a93717169dc0ce25c1da683a0bf1) that I haven't submitted since I haven't tested on my local Mac. If you can try (eg. by doing the following steps) that would be great.

Make a backup and modify `/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list` as follows:

```
Current: yaml https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
New: yaml https://github.com/130s/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
```

then run (adjust ROS distro accordingly):

```
$ rosdep update
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
```

which should install `psutil` via `pip`.

Be sure to roll back the same file once you've done above.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JamesLloyd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6946/jameslloyd/) on 2013-09-20**:
I ran into the same problem - I tried your suggestion but after trying

rosdep install rqt_top

I get the following error

rosdep install rqt_top

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rqt_top

**Comment by [meatspace_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/6971/meatspace_explorer/) on 2013-09-21**:
I'm getting the same error on 10.8.5

**Comment by [manichour](https://answers.ros.org/users/6986/manichour/) on 2013-09-22**:
10.7.x Same error with workaround.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-09-22**:
Sorry, there was a couple of problems with my initial description. I've corrected my post. This worked fine for me so that I've submitted a patch to include psutil into the official rosdep key https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/2187